# How to move text to the left side of html checkbox?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

How to get my text to move to the left side of an HTML checkbox?  The checkbox is rendered as a switcher/toggle (see pic) that comes from Pixeladmin code and is placed on a Bootstrap form that shows from clicking a dropdown, so there is a little something extra going on here, but I simply need the switcher text to move to the left.

Here is the code and how things look. Thanks ahead of time.

[image]

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/js/pixeladmin.min.js"></script>

<form>
  <div class="form-group p-a-2" style="width: 300px;">
    <label for="ail_tts" class="switcher switcher-success ailtts" style="display:block; color:black; text-align:left">
    <input type="checkbox" id="ail_tts" checked="checked" style="text-align:right;">
    <div class="switcher-indicator">
       <div class="switcher-yes">ON</div>
       <div class="switcher-no">OFF</div>
    </div>
    Text to Screech
  </label>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Did you try to simply move "Text to Screech" in your markup ? Like just before the input ?

Comment: 1. Cut. 2. Paste.

Comment: Yes, tried moving it there, and into a span within the label.

Comment: Please tag just one version of Bootstrap.

Comment: Also include all relevant CSS. As you can see from the snippet above, your markup doesn't render what's in your image.

Comment: Found a <script> tag with a lot of css.  Included it. Still not looking same though.  This is some code I inherited.

Comment: It has moved left now, yes.  Just cannot get it to move left in my codebase, which references a lot of local code, css and js.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-+YQ4JLhjyBLPDQt//I+STsc9iw4uQqACwlvpslubQzn4u2UU2UFM80nGisd026JF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<form>
  <div class="form-group p-a-2" style="width: 300px;">
    <label for="ail_tts" class="switcher switcher-success ailtts" style="display:block; color:black; text-align:left">
    Text to Screech
      <input type="checkbox" id="ail_tts" checked="checked" style="text-align:right;">
      <div class="switcher-indicator">
         <div class="switcher-yes">ON</div>
         <div class="switcher-no">OFF</div>
      </div>
    </label>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: How is this different than my code?  Not seeing it, sorry.

Comment: The label text has been moved, just as we suggested in comments above.

Comment: I placed "Text to Screech" before the <input> element

Comment: In my code in the question I got the text to move to the left by making the change you suggested (thanks), but as you can see it is not looking like my pic yet, and I haven't been able to get things to change yet on my local setup by just moving the text.

Comment: Glad your first problem was solved. This seems like you inherited a lot of code for a project. I suggest you make a new question and you can ask me to answer that one if you wish.

Comment: I got a fix from a team member.  He moved the title out of the <label>, put the <label> in a <div> and put the title in a separate <div>.  But your solution does fix the problem as presented in my post and will be likely to help someone, so I'll mark as correct.

Answer (score -1):

Put that checkbox and text in a custom div and make position: relative of that div after that make text div position: absolute and give left:0px it will move text to left, you can do same thing with checkbox div and give right:0px. It will solve your issue.

Comment: None of that is necessary when using a library such as Bootstrap. It's not even necessary with plain HTML. Also, you should demonstrate your solution with a code snippet.